# How important is a statistically significant intercept?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, econometrics, intercept, macroeconomics

I've created the following model:

```
log(consumption) = a + b*log(GDP) + c*log(GDP(-1)) + d*log(consumption(-1))
```

The slope coefficients are all statistically significant, however the intercept has a p-value of 0.1085. How important is this and how will it affect my model?

Comment: The p-value hasn't affected your model at all.  Could you clarify the sense in which you intend us to understand "important"?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I mean to ask, should I reject this model on the grounds that the intercept is not significantly significant?

Comment: I saw some researches were they discard the intercept term if it's not significant

Comment: How you deal with p-values depends on the purpose of your analysis, so it's essential that you include that information in your post.  Since the effect of the constant term can be profound--it looks like you have a time series model in terms of logarithms, so at each time step the exponential of the intercept will *multiply* the consumption estimate, causing it to have an exponentially greater effect over time--so it would be foolish, without much more consideration, to assume that what "some researches" might have done would be appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your question is not entirely clear. But, if you ask if you could/should reestimate the model without the intercept, if it is not *significant*, then have a look at [When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model)  and you will understand that the answer is **NO**, almost surely. If you don't have a very good, specific reason to omit the intercept, don't do it. One reason: Imagine the true value of the intercept nonzero, but small. Then its estimate will be nonsignificant with large probability, but omitting the intercept will then **destroy the unbiasedness of all the other coefficient estimates**.

There are other reasons, discussed in many other posts at this site. See [Should I keep or eliminate an insignificant confounding variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149384/should-i-keep-or-eliminate-an-insignificant-confounding-variable/149388#149388)   or   [Should control variables be included in model if statistically insignificant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69371/should-control-variables-be-included-in-model-if-statistically-insignificant).  While this posts is about predictors, not the intercept, much the same applies.